# Which ROS Distribution release should I use for Huskey?

Tags: ros

I am working on a school project with [Huskey A200](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Husky). The Huskey is about 6 years old. There are different distribution releases (electric, fuerte ... melodic) available: 
[image]

I was planning to following the instructions for [kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic) since it uses Ubuntu 16.04.

So does this mean I can use any of these versions no matter how old the Huskey itself is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I interpret the [Target Platforms (REP3)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) and the sentence

> [Husky fully supports ROS—all of the packages are available](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Husky)

yes, it seems you could use any of the versions. Maybe there is someone who has tested this already and can confirm ...

Comment: Thank you, turns out Husky already has an image file with indigo on it and all the ros and husky packages installed.